# Elassandra installing ingest-attachment plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elassandra

When running

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-attachment
```

I see:

```
org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginCli.main(PluginCli.java:48) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell! class: org.slf4j.helpers.BasicMarker 
jar1: /home/azureuser/elassandra-6.2.3.38/plugins/.installing-2974073780624375496/slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar 
jar2: /home/azureuser/elassandra-6.2.3.38/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
```

How do I resolve this and install an elasticsearch plugin for ingest-attachment that is compatible with elassandra?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :)

From:
https://jarcasting.com/artifacts/com.strapdata.elasticsearch.plugin/ingest-attachment/

or even better try the official site:
https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.strapdata.elasticsearch.plugin/ingest-attachment/6.2.3.31/jar

and click downloads and then zip

Downloaded: ingest-attachment-6.2.3.31.zip

Then run:
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install file:"/home/sampleuser/ingest-attachment-6.2.3.31.zip"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).